# c++ how does a class derived from a template call the template's constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, template-specialization

I didn't really know how to call this thread. 
The situation is the following. I have a template class `Array<T>`:

```
template <typename T> class Array{
private:
    T* m_cData;
    int m_nSize;
    static int s_iDefualtSize;
public:
    Array();
    Array(int nSize);
}
```

Now, I would like to write a specialized class derived from `Array<T>`, holding objects of `class Boxes`:

```
class Boxes{
private:
    double m_dFull;
public:
    Boxes(double dFull=0): m_dFull(dFull) {}
};
```

I do that in the following manner:

```
class BoxesArray : public Array<Boxes>{
public:
    BoxesArray() : Array<Boxes>::Array() {}
    BoxesArray(int nValue) : Array<Boxes>::Array(nValue) {}
}
```

and I add some extra functionality meant solely for `Boxes`. Ok, so here comes confusion number one. Calling `ArrayBoxes()` seem to instantiate an object Array and "prep" this object to hold Boxes, right? But how does it happen (i.e., which part of the above code) that after creating and object `ArrayBoxes` I have it filled already with Boxes? And, the second question, I can see that these Boxes that fill ArrayBoxes are constructed using the default constructor of Boxes (Boxes `m_dFull` is being set to 0) but what if I would like the ArrayBoxes to be instantiated by default using parametric constructor of Boxes (giving, say, Boxes `m_dFull = 0.5`)? Hope with all the edits my question is clear now.

Comment: You don't have to call your parent class' default constructor, it will be called implicitly.

Comment: What does the default constructor of `Array<T>` do? can we see? It also sounds like your not clear on what inheritance means. `ArrayBoxes` is an `Array<Boxes>`, so whatever you did in `Array<Boxes>` default constructor will affect `ArrayBoxes`.

Comment: I'm stretching to understand why `ArrayBoxes() {}` would not work, considering `Array<Boxes>::Array()` takes no arguments,

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put the code to populate the array with `Boxes` fulfilling your requirements in the body of your default constructor, or call a non-default constructor of `Array<Boxes>` that takes the `Boxes` instances you want to have in the member initialization list.

Answer (score 0):

> But how does it happen (i.e., which part of the above code) that after creating and object ArrayBoxes I have it filled already with Boxes?

It appears your `BoxesArray` constructor calls the `Array<Boxes>` constructor. Even if it didn't, C++ will implicitly call it for you.

> And, the second question, I can see that these Boxes that fill ArrayBoxes are constructed using the default constructor of Boxes (Boxes m_dFull is being set to 0) but what if I would like the ArrayBoxes to be instantiated by default using parametric constructor of Boxes (giving, say, Boxes m_dFull = 0.5)?

You need to add a constructor like so in `Array<T>`:
`Array(int nsize, double defval);`

Inside you will construct the array with the boxes calling the default value.