# c++ is default constructor called in parametrized constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, default-constructor

I have the following template class:

```
template<typename T, int nSize> class Stack{
private:
    int m_nCurrentPos;
    Array<T> m_tArray;
public:
    Stack(int nCurrentPos = 0);
    ...
};
```

I would like the default constructor work as follows:

```
template<typename T, int nSize> Stack<T,nSize>::Stack(int nCurrent){ 
    m_nCurrent = nCurrentPos;
    m_tArray = Array<T>::Array(nSize);
};
```

Where Array looks like that:

```
template <typename T> class Array{
private:
    T* m_cData;
    int m_nSize;
    static int s_nDefaultSize;
public:
    Array();
    Array(int nSize);
    ...
};
```

And its constructors are:

```
template<typename T> Array<T>::Array(){
    m_nSize = s_nDefaultSize;
    m_cData = new T[m_nSize];
}
```

and, obviously,

```
template<typename T> Array<T>::Array(int nSize){
    m_nSize = nSize;
    m_cData = new T[m_nSize];
}
```

So, Stack is composed from Array and some extra functionalities. **My problem is** that when in Array I define `s_nDefaultSize` to be say `512`, and I try to instantiate `Stack<int,1024>` I'm getting an exception from class Array, saying that I'm trying to assign two arrays of different length. As soon as I change the code such that `s_nDefaultSize=1024` (so it matches the template's non-type argument `nSize`), everything's fine. So, in other words, the exception occurs as soon as `s_nDefaultSize != nSize`. So, my guess is that in the code above, in the default constructor of `Stack<T,nSize>`, i.e., `m_tArray = Array<T>::Array(nSize);` the `m_tArray` is created by default constructor of Array (employing `s_nDefaultSize`) and only then the compiler tries to assign it to `Array<T>::Array(nSize)` (employing my `nSize` value). Is that correct? And if yes, how can I change this behaviour? [This is another question that I posted yesterday, which, even though is about inheritance, not composition, is very much related to the question in this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437784/c-how-does-a-class-derived-from-a-template-call-the-templates-constructor)  Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Comment: Not a 100% duplicate but it that is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a member initialization list with the constructor of `Stack`:

```
template<typename T, int nSize>
Stack<T,nSize>::Stack(int nCurrent)
  : m_tArray(nSize)
{ 
    m_nCurrent = nCurrentPos;
};
```

As you have it, `m_tArray` will first be default constructed and then assigned to in your constructor. Here, we use the member initialization list to initialize `m_tArray` to the right size immediately.

Comment: Whoa, it works. Thanks! I use init lists but this time I wanted to do something else but initialization, and so I pushed everything into the body of constructor. I will read the links above to fully understand the difference between the two ways. Cheers!